# What is 'dashboard' word after {{block.super}} in django admin template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

```
{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} dashboard{% endblock %}
```

what is that 'dashboard' word between block's ' what does it do ?
i tried removing it and and the result's were ' it caused the table's in admin template messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the django's base template has a template block named `bodyclass`, and the inherited template is adding the css class `dashboard`.

The reason your template is messed up is because your project would have CSS definitions on this class.

You can read more on [django templates and the inheritance structure here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#module-django.template).

Another way to verify this would be to inspect the generated HTML source on the browser. You would notice the placement of the `dashboard` class on the (what it appears to be) the `body` class, and its associated CSS rules.

So, when you remove `dashboard` - the CSS rules are not applied on the body, hence the result

Comment: actually i included the full code in the first line where there was a css link tag but stackoverflow removed it  ' i thought the same that it might be the dashboard.css file name it is referring ' but was not sure ....anyway's thanks for answer

Comment: No, it is not the css file name. It is the class definition that you would see inside the `dashboard.css` file. If you open the css file, you would see something like `.dashboard{` - that is providing the CSS rules to your HTML elements.

Comment: you mean .dasboard{  will work without element's defined without dasboard class?

Comment: no. they wont. YOu need to tell the body to use the class called Dashboard. Only then will those css styles be applied. All i was trying to say was - If you rename the file `dashboard.css` to something else, and update the link reference to that name, your css will still work fine. It does not depend on the filename. It does depend on the class name though.

Comment: well that is another problem i am having bro ' i did'nt find the element which is using dashboard class in entire admin template's ' this thing's default by django admin ......

Comment: i agree on you i already understood the class defination thing

Comment: It does not. That's why you are giving this class name here: `{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} dashboard{% endblock %}`

Comment: for what element ' body ' ? because in dasboard.css i see it specified table's element

Comment: Then may be it is for the table. I thought it was body based on the block name used. You know the code best

Comment: no you was right ' the class name dashboard was defined for body element using super block ' anyway's thank's this confusion finally lead's to answer , really appreciate ' the thing made me confuse was why the class was defined in another template.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting the content of `{% block bodyclass %}` in the child template - which is the default behavior - adding `{{ block.super }}` inside this block in child template allows you to keep the content of this block from the parent template and to add other content to it. See [here](https://gist.github.com/issackelly/928783) a exemplification.
In your case it simply adds a CSS class to your `body` html tag for custom stylization.